# Is there a better way to write this. Trying something till 3 times or success

Tags: vb.net

Basically I want to try something 3 times. If it fails I try again. If it works I move on.

If it keeps failing after 3 times I am out

```
    For i = 1 To 3
        Do
            Dim json = CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1("https://api.bitforex.com/api/v1/market/symbols")
            If json = "" Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            jtok1 = JObject.Parse(json)
            If jtok1.Item("success").ToString = "False" Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop While False
        Exit For
    Next
```

I don't want to use goto. So this is how I do it.

Another way I can think of is to put success as a boolean variable and act accordingly

```
   Dim jtok1 = New JObject
    Dim success As Boolean = False

    For i = 1 To 3
        success = True
        Dim json = CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1("https://api.bitforex.com/api/v1/market/symbols")
        If json = "" Then
            success = False
        End If

        If success Then
            jtok1 = JObject.Parse(json)
            If jtok1.Item("success").ToString = "False" Then
                success = False
            End If
        End If

        If success Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If success = False Then
        Return
    End If
```

How does more profesional programmer do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing retry logic around every code block that needs it, I find it preferable to use a function.  With the validity of the retry function verified,  then you don't need to worry about proper implementation of that logic.  Your written code intent also becomes apparent.

```
''' <summary>
''' Executes a delegate function until success or maxAttempts reached
''' </summary>
''' <param name="codeToRetry">a boolean function delegate containing the code to execute.  Return true if code completed successfully</param>
''' <param name="maxAttempts">maximum number of times <paramref name="codeToRetry"/> is executed </param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Shared Function RetryCode(codeToRetry As Func(Of Boolean), maxAttempts As Int32) As Boolean
    Dim attempts As Int32 = 0
    Dim ret As Boolean = False
    Do While (Not ret) AndAlso (attempts < maxAttempts)
        attempts += 1
        ret = codeToRetry()
    Loop
    Return ret
End Function
```

A rewrite of the original code would look something like the following.  I believe I got successful retrieve logic correct, but verify that it matches your needs.

```
Sub DemoRetryCode()
    Dim jtok1 As New JObject
    Dim json As String
    Dim success As Boolean = RetryCode(Function()
                                        Dim downloadSuccess As Boolean
                                        json = CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1("https://api.bitforex.com/api/v1/market/symbols")
                                        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json) Then
                                            jtok1 = JObject.Parse(json)
                                            downloadSuccess= jtok1.Item("success").ToString <> "False"
                                        End If
                                        Return downloadSuccess
                                      End Function, 3)
End Sub
```

The compiler will emit the closure code to wrap the local variables `json` and `jtok1` and the delegate to make it appear that the locals are passed/returned to/from the delegate function.

Comment: Upvote, very handy. Copied and saved to my code repository with proper attribution of course. :-)

Comment: Using lambda. Interesting

Answer (score 2):

Reversing the logic. Using `<>` instead of `=` seems to lead to more concise and clear code.

```
Dim success as Boolean = False
For i = 1 To 3
    Dim json = CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1("https://api.bitforex.com/api/v1/market/symbols")
    ' If we get something proceed to parsing it else start again the loop
    If json <> "" Then ' or better if Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(json) Then
        jtok1 = JObject.Parse(json)
        ' if the parsing is not false, mission accomplished, else re-loop
        If jtok1.Item("success").ToString <> "False" Then
            success = True
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next

' here you can test for success or not....
```

Comment: only exit if success is true. Awesome. Yes exit for. Sometimes I do do while false to replace "brackets" in C#